# Calculate sum of market in SQL partition by country and index with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have one data set in which I have to calculate sum of market in SQL Server partition by country and index with this condition:

if index is only 1 by country then Indexmark output will be 0 and if index=>1 by country then it will take sum of market values without taking index 1 market value

To be clear,if index value is 1 only then indexmark should be 0 and if index is 1 and greater than 1 then it will take sum of market values without including index 1 market value

Input:

```
Country Index Market  
--------------------
India    1     100
US       1     200
UK       7     400
US       6     600
UK       3     800
```

Output:

```
Country Index Market  IndMark
----------------------------
India    1     100        0
US       1     200      600
UK       7     400     1200
US       6     600      600
UK       3     800     1200
```

I have tried using below SQL query but it is not giving me expected result

```
SELECT 
    Country, Index, Market,
    SUM(Market) OVER (PARTITION BY Country, (Index > 1) AS IndMark
FROM 
    table
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic, and I also can't read the question because the tables aren't formatted properly.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen now formatted

Comment: Pictures are not useful. Replace source data with their CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: *if index is only 1 by country* Do you mean that the value is `1` strictly, or there is only one distinct `index` value (and it may be not `1`)

Comment: index value is 1 only then indexmark should be 0 and if index is 1 and greater than 1 then it will take sum of market values without including index 1 market value

Comment: @codetech is there a case of zero/negative index?

Comment: *if index is 1 and greater than 1 then* But if index is gerater than 1 only? for example, all rows have index=2? or some rows have 2 and some another have 3?

Comment: for index 2 it will fall in index>1 condition then we will take sum of values by that country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT *,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN [Index] > 1 THEN [Market] END) OVER (PARTITION BY [Country]), 0) [IndexMark] 
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dd57b0e80a7fd5cf1f8be3e6f6f0df29).

Comment: Will fail if zero/negative `index` possible, something like `SUM(CASE WHEN [index]=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` is more reliable. If *index is only 1 by country* means "only one distinct value", then `COUNT(DISTINCT index) = 1` must be used.

Comment: *if zero/negative index possible* where did you see zero/negative index?

Comment: AS always OP tells only a part of facts and does not provide all restrictions - so I think that taking all possible variants into account is useful.